Send HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED from ASP.NET Core controller
I need to request client to downgrade http protocol version from 2 to 1.1. Is it possible to send HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED from ASP.NET Core controller. For me it seems that this can be done only on some lower level than we can access in such a controller. But I was told that HttpReceiveClientCertificate does this in case it can't find the certificate.

Do you mean you want to send HTTP 1.1 requests from the httpclient in the controller?

@YuningDuan in case client of my controller uses HTTP 2 I want it to switch to HTTP 1.1

You can create an HTTP client in the controller and use the _httpClientFactory.CreateClient() method to create an HTTP client instance. Then use yarp to let the reverse proxy use http_1_1. Here is an example:
Method:
public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy()
  {
      var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
      var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7247/WeatherForecast/PP/v2?Key=a&Topic=d&Message=c");
      var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           
      return Content(content, response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.ToString());
  }

Yarp configuration  :
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster2",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/WeatherForecast/PP/{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster2": {
        "HttpClient": {
          "SslProtocols": [
            "Tls12"
          ]
        },
        "HttpRequest": {
          "Version": "1.1",
          "VersionPolicy": "RequestVersionExact"
        },
        "Destinations": {
          "cluster2/destination1": {
            "Address": "https://localhost:7258/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




I'm not sure this answers my question. I have a controller what receives HTTP 2 request. I need the client (not my code) to reconnect using HTTP 1.1.
